# Drawing rounded rectangle with transparency in Skia

Tags: transparency, fill, rect, stroke, skia

I'm trying to draw a rounded rectangle with transparency with the library `Skia`.

I get a perfect result if i'm using overlapping without transparency.

But when i'm using transparency, i get this:

[image: overlapping1]

That's what i get when i do not overlap:

[image: gaps]

Even if i modify the radius of the inner rectancle, there're still some overlaps/gabs.

My questitons:

- What is the correct way to caluclate the radius of the inner rectangle, when i can accept some missplaced pixels?
- Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [saveLayerAlpha](https://api.skia.org/classSkCanvas.html#a853514477dff62c15ced03f5141b2eb7) before drawing and then [restore](https://api.skia.org/classSkCanvas.html#a2c68ed85badf62be77bb862b02dd4961) after drawing. This allows you to draw multiple paths, shapes, etc with a "global" alpha applied to the layer.